# jQuery iframeFix on a Sortable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

On my CMS I have a list of thumbnails (Sortable). The thumbnails work great and now I'm writing a plug-in to drag-them to a tinyMCE window.

As the tinyMCE window has an iFrame it doesn't work that well.

jQuery has an **option for Draggables called iframeFix** that works exactly as I need. However that list must be a Sortables. I've looked quite extensively on Google and found no-one with my requirements. Has anyone here on StackOverflow done it?

**Apply the iframeFix to a Sortables?**

If not... I'm on my way to a jQuery plug-in.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've done it. You need to have a DIV on top of the iFrame to let the Draggable/Sortable flow without problems. So I used jQuery to create a DIV right on top of the iframe. Then it show's it when you grab the element and destroys it when you drop it. Works like a charm. If anyone is in need of something like that let me know.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'on top of the iframe'? Can you post some code?

Comment: @andybak Are you having a similar problem? TinyMCE runs in an iFrame... when you drag elements into the iFrame area the mouse sort of stops on the iFrame boundaries for a moment and then goes on. But on the user side makes the interface sluggish. The solution is to position a DIV on top of the iFrame as soon as you drag (slightly larger tough) and you can then drag at will. After you drop remove the DIV previous to any action and your ready to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it.

You need to have a DIV on top of the iFrame to let the Draggable/Sortable flow without problems. So I used jQuery to create a DIV right on top of the iframe. Then it show's it when you grab the element and destroys it when you drop it. Works like a charm. If anyone is in need of something like that let me know.

**update (by popular request):**

On my specific scenario I use the following DIV:

```
<div id="iframeDivFixer" class="ui-draggable-iframeFix" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: none; width: 665px; height: 665px; position: absolute; opacity: 0.001; z-index: 1000; left: 362px; top: 290px; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></div>
```

And, as soon as I grab the thumbnail javascript is used to set the `display` property to `block`. The process is reversed when you release the dragabble.

Comment: Can i make the editor droppable with this logic? can you share your code

Comment: Yes, this would be a great place to actually show the answer.

Comment: @ChristianZiebarth, made the DIV available as requested.

Comment: But when you say "on top" of the IFRAME do you mean "comes before the IFRAME in the code?"

Comment: @ChristianZiebarth, no I'm talking about `z-index`

Comment: @ChristianZiebarth, it doesn't matter where you put the DIV but it aims to solve a different problem. On the question asked the issue was with the draggable not working with TinyMCE. Your example lacks an iFrame or TinyMCE so I'm assuming the core of the problem is different.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24338/discussion-between-christian-ziebarth-and-frankie)

Comment: @Frankie, there actually are iFrames in my example. See the forked discussion for more info: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24338/discussion-between-christian-ziebarth-and-frankie

Answer (score 0):

A seriously old question here, but there's another way to do it using css - `pointer-events:none;` which is supported on all the currently supported browsers (IE11 and above - [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events))

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    start: function() {
        $("iframe").css("pointer-events", "none");
    },
    stop: function() {
        $("iframe").css("pointer-events", "");
    },
});
```