# Preserve IFRAME content on drag with Kendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

The following is my older message from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698419/preserve-iframe-content-on-drag):

> On my current project I am implementing the jHtmlArea WYSIWYG plugin
>   on some TEXTAREA's that are in rows that are draggable and sortable.
>   The only problem is that once you begin dragging them they lose all
>   the data that was in the IFRAME that the plugin masks over the
>   associated TEXTAREA. jQuery's .clone feature is being used but on its
>   own it doesn't carry all the data over with it and even setting it to
>   .clone(true) or .clone(true, true) does not preserve the data on drag....

This question has gone entirely unanswered. Now I am trying to achieve the desired effect with the [Kendo RadEditor](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/editor-getting-started.html) (on a suggestion from somebody else on the project that using Kendo might make it work) but it doesn't seem much better. I wasn't able to put this example into a fiddle, bin or pen:

http://www.cmzmedia.com/kendo/examples/web/editor/all-tools.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproducing this in a simple [jsbin demo](http://jsbin.com/abaveh/1/edit) to no avail. Drag and drop seems to work without losing the content. The code I've used was this:

```
  <textarea class="editor" style="width: 400px">Editable Content</textarea>

  <textarea class="editor" style="width: 400px">Editable Content</textarea>

  <textarea class="editor" style="width: 400px">Editable Content</textarea>

  <textarea class="editor" style="width: 400px">Editable Content</textarea>

  <script>
     $(".editor").kendoEditor().closest(".k-widget").draggable();
  </script>
```